# Why do two rasters with the same spatial reference not align?

Tags: raster, arcmap, alignment

I have two rasters which have the same spatial reference and cell resolution but they are slightly out of line?

Any idea why this is and how I can align them?

I am using ArcMap 10.4.1

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi, please let the community know if the answer below was helpful or not. You can click 'answered' if it answered your question. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Just because they have the same Coordinate Reference System and cell size, does not mean they have to be aligned. This depends on the *origin* of the rasters, i.e. the easting-northing of their lower left corner. Check the 'extent' tab and see if their extents are identical. In more technical terms, they should have an identical [affine transformation](https://www.perrygeo.com/python-affine-transforms.html).

If they are not formally aligned, you can use the [snap raster](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/environments/snap-raster.htm) environment setting to perfectly snap an output raster to a pre-existing raster.